# What is the most idiomatic/best way to abstract over many optional and independent capabilities of types via traits?

Tags: rust, traits

I want to abstract over a variety of different list data structures. My abstraction should be fairly flexible. I want a "base trait" (let's call it `List`) that represents the minimal interface required from all data structures. **But** there are *optional capabilities* the data structures could offer, which are independent from each other:

- Some data structures allow mutation, while others only provide a read-only interface. This is something which is fairly common for Rust traits: the pair `Trait` and `TraitMut` (e.g. `Index` and `IndexMut`).
- Some data structures provide a capability "foo".
- Some data structures provide a capability "bar".

Initially, this seems easy: provide the traits `List`, `ListMut`, `FooList` and `BarList` where the latter three have `List` as super trait. Like this:

```rust
trait List {
    fn num_elements(&self) -> usize;
}

trait ListMut: List {
    fn clear(&mut self);
}

trait FooList: List {
    fn num_foos(&self) -> usize;
}

trait BarList: List {
    fn num_bars(&self) -> usize;
}
```

This works fine for the methods above. **But** the important part is that there are methods that require *multiple* capabilities. For example:

- `add_foo(&mut self)`: requires the mutability *and* the capability "foo"!
- `add_foo_and_bar(&mut self)`: requires mutability *and* the capabilities "foo" *and* "bar".
- ... and more: imagine there is a function for each combination of requirements.

Where should the methods with multiple requirements live?

#### One Trait per Combination of Capabilities

One way would be to additionally create a trait for each combination of optional requirements:

- `FooListMut`
- `BarListMut`
- `FooBarList`
- `FooBarListMut`

These traits would have appropriate super trait bounds and  could house the methods with multiple requirements. There are two problems with this:

- The number of traits would grow exponentially with the number of optional capabilities. Yes, there would only need to be as many traits as methods, *but* it can still lead to a very chaotic API with loads of traits where most traits only contain one/a small number of methods.
- There is no way (I think) to force types that implement `ListMut` and `FooList` to also implement `FooListMut`. Thus, functions would probably need to add more bounds. This trait system would give implementors flexibility I might not want to give them.

#### `where Self` bounds on methods

One could also add `where Self: Trait` bounds to methods. For example:

```rust
trait FooList: List {
    // ...

    fn add_foo(&mut self) 
    where 
        Self: ListMut;
}
```

This also works, but has two important disadvantages:

- Implementors of `FooList` that don't implement `ListMut` would need to dummy implement `add_foo` (usually with `unreachable!()`) because [the Rust compiler still requires it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55521669/compiler-forces-me-to-implement-trait-method-but-the-self-trait-bound-on-metho).
- It is not clear where to put the methods. `add_foo` could also live inside `ListMut` with the bound being `where Self: FooList`. This makes the trait API more confusing.

#### Define Capabilities via associated types/consts

In this solution, there would only be one trait. (Note that in the following code, dummy types are used. Ideally, this would be an associated `const` instead of `type`, but we cannot use consts in trait bounds yet, so dummy types it is.)

```rust
trait Bool {}
enum True {}
enum False {}
impl Bool for True {}
impl Bool for False {}


trait List {
    type SupportsMut: Bool;
    type SupportsFoo: Bool;
    type SupportsBar: Bool;

    fn add_foo(&mut self) 
    where 
        Self: List<SupportsMut = True, SupportsBar = True>;

    // ...
}
```

This solves two problems: for one, we know that if `Mut` and `Foo` are supported, that we can use `add_foo` (in contrast to the first solution, where a data structure could implement `ListMut` and `FooList` but not `FooListMut`). Also, since all methods live in one trait, there it's not unclear anymore where a method should live.

But:

- Implementors still might need to add a bunch of `unreachable!()` implementations as by the last solution.
- It is more noisy to bound for certain capabilities. One could add `trait ListMut: List<SupportsMut = True>` (the same for foo and bar) as trait alias (with blanket impl) to make this a bit better, though.

#### Something else?

The three solutions so far are what I can think of. One could combine them somehow, of course. Or maybe there is a completely different solution even?

---

**Are there clear advantages of one solution over the other solutions? Have they important semantic differences? Is one of these considered more idiomatic by the community? Have there been previous discussions about this? Which one should be preferred?**

Comment: Should `List` implementations have the ability to override `add_foo`, or is there a single implementation based on the capabilities?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yes, implementations should have the ability to override the method. In fact, in most cases it is not possible to provide a default implementation.